# write an iOS 5.1 app that uses a web service

Tags: ios, ios5, xcode4, database-connection, xcode4.4

I am fairly new to iOS programming and I'm trying to make an iOS 5.1 app that communicates with a server to receive information from a database. I got the server returning the needed information from the database by following this tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app

But then I tried to follow a the other half of the tutorial by the same guy:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service

In this one we use JSON, ASIHTTPRequest and MBProgressHUD, but I get a lot of errors when I run this because ASIHTTPRequest is no longer supported in iOS 5.1.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? I you can show me another tutorial that works for iOS 5.1 that would be great. I have looked but I can't find any.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ASIHTTPRequest` is most likely returning errors in your iOS 5.1 app because you're using ARC.  `ASIHTTPRequest` wasn't written in ARC, which is why it's throwing tons of errors.  But there's an easy workaround:

1. In Xcode 4's groups and files pane, select your project file at the top of the list.
2. Select your target towards the left hand panel.
3. You should now see a list of all the implementation (.m) files referenced and compiled throughout the course of the program.
4. Double click the implementation files for `ASIHTTPRequest` and add the following linker flag: `-fno-objc-arc`.  This linker flag acts as a crossbridge between the old non-ARC files and your ARC-based project.

Although there may be residual warnings left, this trick should remove all other error messages associated with `ASIHTTPRequest`.

Comment: Before I do that I have 4 errors and after I do that I have 20. Do I only need to add the flag to ASIHTTPRequest.m? or all the .m files starting with ASI...?

Comment: Are you using ARC in your project?

Comment: Some of there errors say "ARC Casting Rules" and "ARC Restrictions" but I haven't actually added ARC I don't think. How do you tell?

Comment: Are manually typing `retain` and `release` when dealing with objects throughout the course of your app?

Comment: no. It won't let me. I suppose that means I am using ARC. So then how come it doesn't work when we put link the old non-ARC files with it?

Comment: That's strange--I'll have to think on that one. When I used ASIHTTPREQUEST I didn't encounter those issues after adding the linker flag. Why don't we try this: post photos of the errors before and after adding the linker flag. Then I may be able to help you more easily.

Comment: OK. Here are the errors before the flags:
[Before](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/201/screenshot20120731at110.png/), 

And here ther are after:
[After](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/853/screenshot20120731at110.png/)

Comment: Sorry for the delay--You forgot the `c` in the linker flag `-fno-objc-arc`.  Add that and you should be good.

Comment: Lol that's embarassing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When I followed that same tutorial I got a lot of errors. and the build kept failing until I reliased it was because `libz.1.2.3.dylib` wasnt there. If you go to Build Phases, remove that from the list and add `libz.1.2.5.dylib` all mine worked first and I got the app working fully :)